# For what values of $p$ is the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^{p}}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n (\ln n)^p}$

I don't know what to do from here since $p$ is on $\ln$.

Would $p$ still have to be $> 1$ since $\ln$ is changing in terms of $n$?

Comment: [Cauchy condensation theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893299/when-does-sum-frac1n-ln-na-converge/893312#893312)

Comment: This is really classic : Bertrand series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Use [Integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

By Integral test of convergence you calculate the integral $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^p} dt$ (substitution $t=\ln x$).

For $p=-1$ you have $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{t^p} dt=\log|t|+C$, so integral diverges.

For $p \neq -1 $ you have $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{t^p} dt=\frac{p-1}{t^{p-1}}+C$, so for $p<-1$ integral diverges, for $p>-1$ converges.

Comment: This is clearly not true. If $p = -\frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^p} = \frac{\ln{n}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$ (for $n > 3$) so the series must diverge.

Comment: That should say "for $p < 1$ the integral diverges, for $p > 1$ converges".

Answer (score 2):

The [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) easily gives that your series converges iff $p>1$.

Comment: I have a little question, note that $\sum 2^{n}a_{2^{n}}=\sum \frac{1}{2^n(ln(2^n))^p}$, but this is equal to $\sum \frac{1}{n^{p}}$ but why from this $(ln(2^n))^p$ to this $n^{p}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: By the integral test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n (\ln n)^p}$ converges iff $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x(\ln x)^p}$ converges.

Now substitute $u = \ln x$ into that integral, and see what you get.