# Decide whether the following series converges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Looking for a neat and smart way to solve this.

I am having a tough time with this

Comment: $\ln n$ grows more slowly than any power of $n$.

Comment: This is simply [$\zeta''\bigg(\dfrac32\bigg)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: thankyou everyone, u guys deserve this  http://i.imgur.com/sHxpw1t.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta (n)} $ for nonnegative $\alpha$ and $\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267697/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-alpha-ln-beta-n-for)

Answer (score 3):

We have (we can prove it using the L'Hôpital's rule)

$$(\ln n)^2=o(n^{1/3})$$
so

$$\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{3/2}}=o\left(\frac1{n^{\frac32-\frac13}}\right)$$
and since $\frac32-\frac13>1$ we conclude by comparison with a Riemann convergent series that the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Claim 1.
$$
\sum \frac{1}{n^\alpha}<\infty,\quad \forall \alpha>1
$$

Claim 2. For any $\beta >0$,
$$
\ln n<n^\beta, \quad n\gg 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You know that there exist such a $N$, that for $n>N$ you have($\varepsilon>0$):

$$\ln n < n^{\varepsilon}$$

So for $n>N$:

$$\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\frac{n^{2 \varepsilon}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-2\varepsilon}}$$

If you choose $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{4}$, then $\frac{3}{2}-2\varepsilon>1$, so the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}-2\varepsilon}}$$

converges, so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\ln n)^2}{n^{3/2}}$ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using Cauchy condensation theorem which allows us to consider instead the series

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^{n/2}}  $$

which is a convergent series if it is copared with the geometric series $\sum_{n}x^n$ with the condition of convergence $|x|<1$. See [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893299/when-does-sum-frac1n-ln-na-converge/893312#893312).

**Cauchy Condensation Theorem:**

> For a positive non-increasing sequence $f(n)$, the sum
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)  $$
>   converges if and only if the sum
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})$$
>   converges.

Answer (score 0):

well I was trying in this way,we know,$$\forall x\ge1 $$ $$\frac{1}{x}\le\frac{1}{x^\frac{4}{5}}$$so$$\int^n_1\frac{1}{x}dx\le\int^n_1\frac{1}{x^\frac{4}{5}}dx$$i.e.$$log(n)\le 5n^\frac{1}{5}-5<5n^\frac{1}{5}$$$\Rightarrow$$$(log(n))^2<25n^\frac{2}{5}$$$\Rightarrow$$$\frac{(log(n))^2}{n^\frac{3}{2}}<25\frac{1}{n^\frac{11}{10}}$$$\Rightarrow$$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(log(n))^2}{n^\frac{3}{2}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}25\frac{1}{n^\frac{11}{10}}$$ RHS converges and hence LHS converges
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^t}$$converges iff t>1